# Reading a line from a text file using commas as delimiter

Tags: python, text, file-io, delimiter

I'm in the process of trying to read different lines from a text file.

Current i have a program that can read the follow type of line from a text file if it follows this format:

```
6361550850261,SHOWALL
APN="3"
IGF=15
VOW=117
VWD=12
[+][+]52
```

Using this code:

```
def make_dict(data):
    return dict((line.split(None, 1)[0], line)for line in data)

def process(infile, outfile, keywords):
    keys = [[k[0], k[1], 0] for k in keywords]
    endk = None
    with open(infile, 'rb') as fdin:
        with open(outfile, 'ab') as fdout:
            fdout.write("|<" + words + ">|" + "\r\n")
            for line in fdin:
                if endk is not None:
                    fdout.write(line)
                    if line.find(endk) >= 0:
                        fdout.write("\r\n")
                        endk = None
                else:
                    for k in keys:
                        index = line.find(k[0])
                        if index >= 0:
                            fdout.write(line[index + len(k[0]):].lstrip())
                            endk = k[1]
                            k[2] += 1
    if endk is not None:
        print 'Serial Number not Found'
        raise Exception(endk + "Not found before end of file")
    return keys
```

where `infile` is the file im reading from, `outfile` is the output text file, and `keywords` is the serial number i am looking for in the text file.

this works fine for this type of formatted text.
However if i have the following text instead:

```
*GS,6361550850261,211635181215,,APN;"3",IGF:A;15;VOW:117,VWD;12,ADC:12.40;[+][+]52
```

Notice how rather than whitespaces I have commas separating the data using them as the delimiter.

How can i go about using the same idea as the top text file.

So in general I'm just trying to read a line that is using this format rather than the other format.

EDIT:

So as an Output Example:
If i have this line:
`*GS,6361550850261,211635181215,,APN;"3",IGF:A;15;VOW:117,VWD;12,ADC:12.40;[+][+]52`

into this:

`*GS
6361550850261
211635181215
APN:"3"
IGF:A;15
VOW:117
VWD:12
ADC:12.40`

Comment: Have you tried `line.split(',')`?

Comment: What's wrong with the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: I haven't tried the CSV module since I've been trying to just alter my current `process` definition to fit this. Ill look into using `csv`

Comment: Could you show what your expected output would be? Does the script need to work with both of your sample inputs?

Comment: @MartinEvans I added an example of my output

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by the commas in it:

```
>>> s = '*GS,6361550850261,211635181215,,APN;"3",IGF:A;15;VOW:117,VWD;12,ADC:12.40;[+][+]52'
>>> lines = [line for line in s.split(',') if line]
>>> lines
['*GS', '6361550850261', '211635181215', 'APN;"3"', 'IGF:A;15;VOW:117', 'VWD;12', 'ADC:12.40;[+][+]52']
```

Now you can iterate over these lines to process them as you see fit.

Note that this code as-is will probably not solve your problem since you have discrepancies in the syntax of your examples. Please take note and re-adapt my answer to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For your given input example, the following function should give you the results you need:

```
import csv

def process(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile, 'rb') as f_input, open(outfile, 'w') as f_output:
        for cols in csv.reader(f_input):
            output = cols[0:3]                          # *GS + 2 numbers
            output.append(cols[4].replace(';', ':'))    # APN
            output.extend(cols[5].rsplit(';', 1))       # IGF and VOW
            output.append(cols[6].replace(';', ':'))    # VWD
            output.append(cols[7].rsplit(';', 1)[0])    # ADC
            f_output.write('\n'.join(output))
            f_output.write('\n')
```

This will produce an output file containing:

```
*GS
6361550850261
211635181215
APN:"3"
IGF:A;15
VOW:117
VWD:12
ADC:12.40
```

The Python `csv` module automatically splits each line of your file into a list of entries. By default this works on commas.

You may need to provide more sample lines, as this is quite dependent on the format of the existing line.

Tested using Python 2.7.9